# Why `args[0].Trim() == null` is always false?

Tags: c#

I have a method like this:

```
public string StartCapture(string[] args)
{
    if(args[0].Trim() == null || args[0].Trim() == string.Empty )
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Why I get a note that `args[0].Trim() == null` will always be false?

Comment: As an aside. I believe this method would be of use to you: [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (.Net 4.0 only).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Trim()` is not going to return null. The issue you might have is if `args[0]` is null, or `args` itself is null, but the result of `Trim()` will never be null, and therefore the comparison to null will always be false.

[Trim Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

> If the current string equals Empty or all the characters in the current instance consist of white-space characters, the method returns Empty.

You may want to simply check

```
 if (args == null || args.Length == 0 || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args[0]))
 {
     // null or empty array or empty first element
 }
```

Comment: Why do you check if the length of the string is 0, if that is the case then its an empty string. Why don't you is **IsNullOrEmpty**?

Comment: Where have I checked the length of the string? I have only compared the *array* against null, I have checked the length of the *array* for 0 elements, and then I have checked the first element *only if there is one.* Remember, in the question, it is `string[] args`.

Answer (score 3):

If `args[0]` is `null`, then you'll get a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) when you try to *call* the `Trim()` method. There is no possible path of execution in which a `null` value is available for the `==` comparison.

You *might* want:

```
if(args[0] == null || args[0].Trim() == string.Empty )
{
```

But more probably want:

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(args[0]))
{
```

[String.IsNullOrWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) was introduced in .NET 4

Answer (score 2):

`Trim()` is defined to *always* return a value, therefore, it can never be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Because null is not an object, while string.empty (which is "") is a string object with a length of 0 characters.